# Win7, UAC disabled: processes do not start as Administrator by default

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, administrator, uac

I have a very strange bhaviour in Windows 7: I have a system that has several Administrator Users, and even the built-in Administrator Account is active. These other Administrator-Users all have UAC disabled, so normally, every process a user starts should start as Administrator by default. For example, you run cmd.exe, then the title-bar should look like `Administrator: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` This is the case on all my other test systems with UAC disabled, except for that specific system.

As I said, the user belongs to the Administrators group. When I open regedit.exe, I can see that under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-{SID}-1000`, the `REG_DWORD:State` is always set to 0, whereas all the working systems have that state set to 256 instead. I am not sure what finally sets that state, but as far as I understand does 256 (0x100) mean `PROFILE_ADMIN_USER`, which is what I want the state to be.

If I set it manually to 0x100, and restart my system, it will be reset to 0 by the system.

So something is causing this account not to be a "real" Administrative account. The question is: how can I force this account to start all programs as Administrator, as long as UAC is disabled?

Comment: "If I set it manually to 0x100, and restart my system, it will be reset to 0 by the system." = This tells me the system is connected to an activate domain which is enforcing a group policy

Comment: I don't have a domain, in fact, the computer is not even connected to a network. I thought that "state" actually may be only a read-only value (not technically, but intended to be) that is set elsewhere from the system. But I can't find any good documentation about it.